# Is there a drawback to using an inplace function within map/filter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Is there any drawback to using a function like *map* to apply an inplace function to a list? For example, could the fact that the *map* function produces an output be "harmful/negative"? My understanding is that *map* is slightly more efficient than a *for loop*.

See the following two methods to achieve the same result:

```
lists = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
map(lambda l: l.sort(), lists)
```

vs.

```
lists = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
for l in lists:
    l.sort()
```

The question is just to satisfy my curiosity and to understand better how python works. It is not to discuss which method is cleaner or more pythonic.

Comment: no they don't. Because you're using `map` for a side effect, but in python 3 you have to iterate on it anyway so "smart looking" python 2 code won't do the job on python 3.

If you want side-effects, keep the loop.

Comment: In 2.x, map will build a list of N `None`s which you don't need - so that's not great. Also - you're introducing the overhead of a `lambda` to do the sort... (although technically you could do `map(list.sort, lists)` but that's still ugly and undesirable) And in 3.x, unless you deliberate iterate over it - nothing will happen anyway. Stick to the for-loop... General rule of thumb: If you want to keep the output then use map or a comprehension of some sort, if you don't use a loop.